# "Bayesian Methods for Hackers" jupyter notebook not working

Tags: tensorflow2.0, bayesian, tensorflow-probability

I am reading the online TensorFlow Probability (TFP) version of "Bayesian Methods for Hackers".

But when I excecute the first cell of [Ch2_MorePyMC_TFP.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter2_MorePyMC/Ch2_MorePyMC_TFP.ipynb#scrollTo=jFKYjxy1IAwG)
the following error occurs:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

I suppose this version of "Bayesian Methods for Hackers" jupyter notebook was written for TF1.

Do you have an easy fix or a updated version of this jupyter notebook working with TF2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the `contrib` functions are removed and some of them are merged into `TensorFlow` core. You need to find the equivalent version of them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

print(tf.__version__) # 2.5.0
print(tfp.__version__) # 0.12.1
```

For example first contrib functions are available in TensorFlow and can be re-written as:

```
parameter = tfd.Exponential(rate=1., name="poisson_param").sample()
rv_data_generator = tfd.Poisson(parameter, name="data_generator")
data_generator = rv_data_generator.sample()


data_generator_ = tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(
     data_generator,
     [t.numpy() if tf.is_tensor(t) else t
     for t in tf.nest.flatten(data_generator)])

print("Value of sample from data generator random variable:", data_generator_)
```

---

For other TF Operations you can replace them like this:

```
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
    step_size = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
        name='step_size',
        initializer=tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float32),
        trainable=False,
        use_resource=True
    )
```

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#5_migrate_off_compatv1_symbols)

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean and I will try. But that's a lot of work at almost each cells. And it's sometimes not so obvious to fix (at least for me). So if someone has a link to an updated version of this book, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Frightera, I have problems getting rid of the following error :

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'

at cell :

```
# Initialize the step_size. (It will be automatically adapted.)
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    step_size = tf.get_variable(
        name='step_size',
        initializer=tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float),
        trainable=False,
        use_resource=True
    )
```

Do you have any clue how to replace this one?

Comment: Thanks a lot. PS: I don't close the issue after your great answer because I also wait for a possible up to date version of this online book if anyone made this job before (or after) me (on the 6 chapters).